# Why can't I post a simple HTML on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, quality-filter

This is the third time I am trying to post an issue I got with bootstrap and HTML and I everytime I come here, it doesn't allow me to post. It either says "Your post is mostly code, try writing something" or it says "format your code with 4 spaces" (which I did).

Anyways, what is this thing? How comes other people have posted stuff? Have all of them been posted by the owner of the website with "super user" power?

I hate it. I think we (everyone else) should come together and build "free poster" so people can post code and ask for help.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to post?  Your suggestion that users should make a site where they can post code to get help is a bit odd, since that's pretty much what Stack Overflow _is_.

Comment: Well, if you **only** have code, where is the question? We expect a problem description (plus what you already tried and any errors/exceptions etc).

Comment: The system works. Good luck building your own Q&A site!

Comment: @Yousef try posting the question as a quote exactly as you'd post it on SO?

Answer (score 5):

It really works if you write some text here and indent the html with 4 spaces - Highlight the code and click the <kbd>{ }</kbd>  works too

```
<div class="head">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
      <div class="span6">
        <h1 class="muted">Company Name</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="span4 offset2" style="margin-top:15px;">
        <button type="button" class="btn pull-right">Sign In</button>   
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="#">Explore Product</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li> 
       </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! You must be the owner of the site, who uses super powers. ;)